# Javascript and HTML5 loop issue

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia

I'm trying to create a simple loop recording program in HTML5.  I have some of the basics done but the problem I'm having now is when I try to play the audio recursively it keeps firing the method before the audio is finished or way after.

I tried to set a setTimeout but thats only confusing me as what I *thought* would be a correct interval just confused me more.  Could someone please look over this?

You can also find an active site http://rossb.byethost11.com/

```js
        /*
         * finds duration of sound file in milliseconds
         */
        function getMasterDuration() {
          var sound = document.getElementById("session-1");
          var returnValue = sound.duration * 1000;
          return returnValue;
        }


        /*
         * called from the button
         */

        function playAllService() {
          //set up recursive loop to play sounds
          window.setInterval(recursivePlay, getMasterDuration);
        }

        function recursivePlay() {
            //play all sounds
            playAll();
            //set timeout until sound is done (?)
            setTimeout(recursivePlay, getMasterDuration);
          }
          /*
           * Finds all the recording sessions and plays them.
           */

        function playAll() {
          for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSessions; i++) {
            play(i);
          }
        }
```

And yes, I know it needs cleanup.

Thanks for the help!

Edit for Clarification: I want it to loop without any breaks. like a loop petal or drum machine.

Comment: Do not post the whole code! Please try to narrow down to a particular block that you think is causing the problem, or which is relevant to the functionality in the question.

Comment: @surajck okay edited the post. Thanks.

From this block you can see that the playAllService function is being called from the page.  I want the audio tracks to loop over and over without any pause inbetween.  Think of it like a guitar loop petal or a drum machine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a function *without* parentheses, you're referring to the function itself.  So a call to `recursivePlay` returns this:

```
function recursivePlay() {
  //play all sounds
  playAll();
  //set timeout until sound is done (?)
  setTimeout(recursivePlay, getMasterDuration);
}
```

This is correct for the first parameter to `setTimeout`, because you want the *function* to run after an interval.

The second parameter to `setTimeout` is expected to be a number (in milliseconds).  However, you're returning the *function* `getMasterDuration` instead of the *result* of the function.

To fix that, simply add parentheses to `getMasterDuration`:

```
setTimeout(recursivePlay, getMasterDuration());
```

Comment: Thanks! Derp! I completely over looked that.

Comment: Now i'm facing the issue that the file is trying to play thousands of times during the loop.  I have updated the live example, if you look at the dev console you can see the issue.

Comment: `playAllService` calls `recursivePlay` every `getMasterDuration()` milliseconds, and `recursivePlay` calls itself every `getMasterDuration()` milliseconds.  So you may not need `playAllService`.  (Also note that there's no "a" in metronome.)

Comment: When I remove playAllService and call recursivePlay by itself the sound files play with a large delay before it repeats.

Comment: My thought was that playAllServices would call recursivePlay, which would play the files (via playAll) and then set a delay to the length of the audio file before looping again. Apparently this is not the way to go. 

I feel like this is a simple solution and i'm being dumb. 

Thanks for the help Rick!

Comment: If you don't want any delay, you can change `setTimeout(recursivePlay, getMasterDuration());` to something like this: `setTimeout(recursivePlay, 1);`

Comment: Okay thanks Rick.

I think I found part of the problem.  I had a generic play() function that was checking to see if the audio was paused, and if so then it would play the audio.  Same goes for if it was playing, then the function would pause it. (like a toggle).  

When I changed setTimeout to 1 it was calling that generic play() and playing/pausing tons of times.  I have now removed the play() check and it works.  My only concern is that the timeout is still calling the play function 1000+ plus times unnecessarily..... but at least it works now. so yay for progress.

thanks Rick!

Comment: Progress is good.  You could assign a variable to `setTimeout`, then call `clearTimeout` with that variable to stop the playing.  See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp